# Sequelize destroy cannot be tested for truthiness

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, sequelize.js, graphql

I've been getting this error warning out of a sudden when trying to destroy a record on sequelize using Typescript. I'm using Visual Studio Code as my editor.

[image: vscode error message]

Does anyone know how to fix this annoying error message and return the truthiness value?

Comment: It's just the Linter, Does it work or not?

Comment: It does work. This error message wasn't showing before though.

Comment: Whats your editor? and what linter its using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code, but I don't know what linter it uses.

Comment: It will "work" in that the record is deleted but the above will always resolve to `false` as `e` is `undefined` in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a legitimate error, `e` will always be void/undefined when you call [`Instance.destroy()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html#destroying-deleting-persistent-instances) on an object returned by Sequelize as the "success" is void (see documentation link).

You are likely confusing it with [`Model.destroy({ where: ... })`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-destroy) which will return an `Integer` indicating the number of rows deleted.

To return `true` when it is deleted and `false` when there is an error use the following (note that this will swallow errors):

```
return device.destroy().then(() => true).catch(() => false);
```